# Win 32 API set window minimum size to keep text fully visible

Tags: api, winapi, window

I am currently a beginner in win 32 API and am making a sample program. The problem I face is I can't find a proper way to set the window's minimum size in order for the text inside it (centered) to be visible when the window gets at its minimum. The text is fully visible in all the other cases, except when I reach a certain "critical" size, after which the  text is either seen partially or not seen at all.

I found how to change the width and height of the window, as shown here:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)        
{
    switch (message)                  
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);      
            break;

        case WM_GETMINMAXINFO: 
            ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.x =100; //apply custom min width
            ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y =100;  //apply custom min height
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

            GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);

            DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("Sample text here"), -1, &rc,DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER ) ;


            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

        default:                      
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think these lines should be changed, but I don't know what change needs to be made.

```
((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.x =100; //apply custom min width
((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y =100;  //apply custom min height
```

My idea is that instead explicit float values which are assigned to x and y members of the POINT structure, a function should be called, that determines the text's minimum width and height.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the full code of this program.

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");
RECT rc;
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR lpszArgument,
                 int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */

    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       _T("Code::Blocks Template Windows App"),
              /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       544,                 /* The programs width */
       375,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    return messages.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       
            break;

        case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
            //window size/position is going to change
            //apply custom min width/height 350,50

            SIZE sz;
            HDC hdc = GetDC( hwnd );
            TCHAR* myString = TEXT("Sample Text!");
            HFONT oldFont, myFont; //create your own font
            //select your font into device context
            oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject( hdc, myFont );
            //get font dimensions
            GetTextExtentPoint32( hdc, myString, _tcslen( myString ), &sz );

            ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.x = sz.cx;
            ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y = sz.cy;

            //cleanup
            SelectObject( hdc, oldFont );
            DeleteObject( myFont );
            ReleaseDC( hwnd, hdc );
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);
                GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);
                DrawText (hdc, TEXT("Sample Text!"), -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK ) ;
                EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
            }
            break;

        default:                      
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I apologize for the poor indentation.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.  100 is arbitrary and rather small.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try to copy and paste the code-it should work. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you want so you can calculate the text size and length. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the example showing how to use it.

Just in case your text gets bigger dimensions than your screen, you could add `DT_WORDBREAK` flag to your [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call-see the documentation.

You will need to create font and select it in your device context and [`CreateFontIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can help you-pay attention to the members of the [`LOGFONT structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you can create font you wish. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is one example of doing it.

Try something like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

        //create your own font
        HFONT oldFont, myFont; 
        // create logical font for menu
        LOGFONT lf = { sizeof(lf) };
        _tcscpy_s( lf.lfFaceName, ARRAYSIZE(lf.lfFaceName), L"Microsoft Sans Serif" );
        lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv( 12, GetDeviceCaps( hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
        lf.lfWeight = FW_HEAVY;
        lf.lfItalic = FALSE;
        lf.lfUnderline = FALSE;

        myFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        //select your font into device context
        oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject( hdc, myFont );

        GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);
        DrawText (hdc, TEXT("Sample Text!"), -1, &rc, 
            DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK ) ;

        //cleanup
        SelectObject( hdc, oldFont );
        DeleteObject( myFont );

        EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0L;

case WM_GETMINMAXINFO: 
    {
        SIZE sz;
        HDC hdc = GetDC( hwnd );
        LPTSTR myString = TEXT( "Sample text here" );

        //create your own font 
        HFONT oldFont, myFont; 

        // create logical font for menu
        LOGFONT lf = { sizeof(lf) };
        _tcscpy_s( lf.lfFaceName, ARRAYSIZE(lf.lfFaceName), L"Microsoft Sans Serif" );
        lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv( 12, GetDeviceCaps( hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
        lf.lfWeight = FW_HEAVY;
        lf.lfItalic = FALSE;
        lf.lfUnderline = FALSE;

        myFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        //select your font into device context
        oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject( hdc, myFont );

        //get font dimensions
        GetTextExtentPoint32( hdc, myString, _tcslen( myString ), &sz );

        ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.x = sz.cx; 
        ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y = sz.cy; 

        //cleanup
        SelectObject( hdc, oldFont );
        DeleteObject( myFont );
        ReleaseDC( hwnd, hdc );
    }
break;
```

If you have further questions leave a comment.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggested code, but when I try to run it, the compiler gives the following errors:

1) crosses initialization of 'TCHAR* myString'
2) crosses initialization of 'HDC__* hdc'

I think this is an obvious error, but I can't seem to grasp its solution.

Comment: I use Code Blocks. I tried to change LPTSTR to TCHAR and it doesn't seem to help. I think that the error is also present here:
HDC hdc = GetDC( hwnd );

Maybe also the error is because I repeat HDC and String declaration in WM_GETMINMAXINFO as in WM_PAINT, although I am not sure about it.
Anyway, thank for your answer, I'll mark it as useful!

Comment: I posted the full code of the program. The errors that I specified are the only one relevant to this problem (the other one is error: jump to case label)

Comment: You need to enclose your `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` handler in parentheses `{}`-look at my code. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The reason for the error is funny enough to avoid commenting it. It compiles now without any trouble.Now I guess,there is another small issue.The window,at its minimum(when it reaches the smallest adjusted frame),keeps the width of the string (the text is fully displayed, but the height of the window still is very small and the text is not seen. However, when I modify 
((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y = sz.cy; to ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y = sz.cy* (a value); by trials and errors, I find the necessary height. Is there a more rational way to do it?

Comment: @v01d: I have experimented a little by changing the font size. I just can not find a solution. Take my advice and **unaccept** my answer so others can try to help as well. **You can always accept it again later if it suits you.** This way someone might edit my answer or post a solution for helping you with the height of the window. I will try to find a solution for this, and will update my answer if I find anything. Good luck and best regards.